# Best way to monitor SQL Azure database server

Tags: azure-sql-database

I've been getting some warnings about high utilization on our SQL Azure database server.  What is the best way to monitor the utilization of that machine and try to analyze what is causing the high utilization spikes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Log into the Azure management portal http://manage.windowsazure.com 
Select your SQL Database that you interested in getting details on.
Select monitor 
Let’s say you want to monitor your DTU %.  Click on that line item.
Select ADD RULE
Name the rule and describe it
Specify who you want to receive the alerts.

This flow with screen shots can be found here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mschray/archive/2015/09/04/monitoring-your-sql-database-in-azure.aspx

Answer (score 1):

sys.resouce_stats and sys.resource_usage can be used for monitoring the resource usage. Query store feature in SQL DB v12 helps you debugging the performance issues:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/query-store-a-flight-data-recorder-for-your-database/

Answer (score 0):

Using Dynamic Management Views
Azure SQL Database enables a subset of dynamic management views to diagnose performance problems 
 
take look here [DMV sql azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ff394114.aspx)